# PHP & Javascript :A generic way to create a javascript dictionary using php

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to send JavaScript array to PHP script using GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156054/whats-the-best-way-to-send-javascript-array-to-php-script-using-get)

I just want to know that what is the best way to create a javascript dictionary .

Like suppose i have a php array and i want to feed the value of that array(loop iteration )

to a javascript dictionary in the form of key value ?

Comment: more in the Related Section. [Please use the search function before asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about supplying the whole array (which it seems you would like to do), you can simply use `json_encode` on the array to encode it as JSON (which is a subset of JavaScript).